# Suggestion for book on topological group and other topics.

Tags: book-recommendation, topological-groups

What is a great book where I can find the following topics:

> **1. Topological groups**;
>
> **2. Topological properties of orthogonal group $O(n)$;**
>
> **3. Topological properties of special orthogonal group $SO(n)$**; for example $SO(n)$ is compact, path-connected etc.

Thanks!

Comment: Community wiki?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that John Stillwell's *Naive Lie Theory* would be a good choice.